# How to log SQL values sent to my DB using EclipseLink?

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I use EclipseLink as my JPA2 persistence layer, and i would like to see the values sent to DB in logs.

I already see SQL queries (using `<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />` in my persistence.xml), but, for example in an SQSL INSERT, I do not see the values, only the placeholders `?`

So, how to see what values are sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a JDBC proxy driver like [p6spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/) or [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) to get the SQL statements issued with their values instead of the placeholders. This approach works well you are using a EclipseLink with a connection pool whose URL is derived from `persistence.xml` (where you can specify a JDBC URL recognized by the proxy driver instead of the actual), but may not be so useful in a Java EE environment (atleast for [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/wiki/FAQ)), unless you can get the JNDI data sources to use the proxy driver.